# Can I have an IV which does not have main effect on DV directly but might have an interaction effect with another IV on DV?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-regression, interaction, multicollinearity

I am inducing envy (IV 1) to see the effect on focusing illusion/anchoring bias (DV).

Since I am going to induce envy by showing attractive others' pictures,then gender will play a role because females will be more envious than male when in attractiveness domain.

However gender has no relation (no main effect) on focusing illusion at all. I hypothesize that envious female will experience more focusing illusion than envious male.

My question is since gender is not related to focusing illusion independently, can it be an IV first of all? Or I have everything messed up here?

Quick help is greatly appreciated here. Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. Just include envy, gender, and their interaction in the model. The independent variables do not need to appear associated with the dependent variable for you to include their interaction term, though at least one of them usually is. In fact, it is often recommended, for several reasons, that independent variables with no association to the dependent variable should be kept in the model if the interaction term is associated with the dependent variable.

Comment: thanks for your help Berge. so do you think it is better for me to carry out multiple regression since my both IVs  are highly correlated to each other (mutlicollinearity) or can i just carry on with ANOVA too see the interaction?

Comment: Try it out. (if you do it right, you will get *exactly* the same results)

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Is the correlation between gender and envy really so high that it might be a problem?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how strong is the correlation between gender and envy yet. All i know is that gender plays a role in inducing envy via attractiveness. Can i still carry out ANOVA even if both my IVs are strongly correlated? My supervisor said it is not wrong but strange. What does that mean?

Comment: I don't think they will be so strongly correlated that it will be an issue (above 0.7 or so), but if they are, you can still use them but the power to detect the effect of each may be decreased and the results might be difficult to interpret. Also, if the correlation is very high, the interaction might be even more difficult to detect.